# pass dictionary key to CFDictionaryGetValue

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, swift2, cfdictionary

I am getting a headache due to UnsafePointer in Swift.

This is the method I want to call:

```
func CFDictionaryGetValue(theDict: CFDictionary!, _ key: UnsafePointer<Void>) -> UnsafePointer<Void>
```

And this is how I do it.

```
 let ds: SCDynamicStoreRef = SCDynamicStoreCreate(nil, "setNet" as CFString, nil, nil)!


let list = SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies(ds)

print(list!)
print(CFDictionaryGetValue(list, UnsafePointer("HTTPPort")))
```

This however returns an error. I have no idea how to pass dictionary key to this method. If I remove the `UnsafePointer("HTTPPort")` and use `"HTTPPort"` instead I get a runtime error."

How can you access the dictionary values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to take advantage of the toll-free bridging
between `CFDictionary` and `NSDictionary`, and use the `NSDictionary`
accessor methods:

```
let ds = SCDynamicStoreCreate(nil, "setNet", nil, nil)!

if let list = SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies(ds) as NSDictionary? {
    if let port = list[kSCPropNetProxiesHTTPPort as NSString] as? Int {
        print("HTTPPort:", port)
    }
}
```

But just for the sake of completeness: It *can* be done with
`CFDictionaryGetValue`:

```
if let list = SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies(ds)  {
    let key = kSCPropNetProxiesHTTPPort
    let port = unsafeBitCast(CFDictionaryGetValue(list, unsafeAddressOf(key)), NSObject!.self)
    if port != nil {
        print("HTTPPort:", port)
    }
}
```

Comment: It turned out that the dictionary returned is read only. If you have time and are know about system configuration framework feel free to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175502/set-current-proxy-settings