# set current proxy settings

Tags: macos, cocoa

I used `SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies` to retrieve proxy information. I was hoping that once I had the dictionary, I would be able to set current proxy settings. It turned out that the dictionary returned by `SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies` is read only. How can I change current proxy settings?

What I have tried so far:

```
 func setNet(){

        let ds: SCDynamicStoreRef = SCDynamicStoreCreate(nil, "setNet" as 
        CFString, nil, nil)!

        let list = SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies(ds)
        print(list!)

        if let list = SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies(ds) as NSDictionary? {
            if let port = list["HTTPPort"] as? Int {
                print("HTTPPort:", port)
                list["HTTPPort"] = 8088; // error, subscript is get-only
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a "read only" (aka non-mutable) dictionary use `func mutableCopy() -> AnyObject`.

Comment: Thanks. I think system configuration framework didn't mean to trick dictionary into a mutable. I tried that but i am getting all kind of weird errors