# SCDynamicStoreSetValue returns false

Tags: macos, cocoa, system-configuration

I tried updating the proxy settings of my mac. `SCDynamicStoreSetValue:` returned false, indicating an unsuccessful update. This is the code I use. What is the correct way?

```
let ds: SCDynamicStoreRef = SCDynamicStoreCreate(nil, "setProxy" as CFString, nil, nil)!

        let isUpdated = SCDynamicStoreSetValue(ds, "HTTPProxy" as CFStringRef, "111.111.111.1")

        if isUpdated{
            print("updated")
        }else{
            print("not updated")
        }
```

The question is about why SCDynamicStoreSetValue returns false and how to circumvent it.

Comment: The dynamic store contains network services which contain dictionaries for the proxy settings. You need to get the dictionary of the requested service, see [The System Configuration Schema](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_UnderstandSchema/SC_UnderstandSchema.html)

Comment: Okay, the dictionary in question is Proxies dictionary. I can get it like this:         let dict = SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies(ds). Where should the dictionary be passed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set current proxy settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175502/set-current-proxy-settings)

Comment: the question is about why SCDynamicStoreSetValue returns false.

Comment: Run it as superuser, same for `SCDynamicStoreNotifyValue`.

Answer (score 2):

After `SCDynamicStoreSetValue` fails, call `SCError()` to obtain the error code:

```
let errorCode = SCError()
```

Or obtain the error as a string with:

```
let errorString = String.fromCString(SCErrorString(SCError()))
```

In either case, review the [Status and Error Codes for the System Configuration Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SystemConfiguration_Utilities/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Status_and_Error_Codes). That should provide you with the reason that `SCDynamicStoreSetValue` is returning false.

(If your app is Sandboxed, the likely reason is `kSCStatusAccessError`, or "Permission Denied". Sandboxed apps can't set those values.)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but the third argument of `SCDynamicStoreSetValue` should be a `CFPropertyListRef` (in our case a `CFString`, not a string), as in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1437814-scdynamicstoresetvalue?language=objc)

In my case this was causing the function call fail.